# How can I convert a Parameter Expression into a function?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, expression

If I have a dynamically created `ParameterExpression`:

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var propertyName = "Name";

var propertyType = typeof(Product).GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(propertyType , propertyName);
```

How can I covert it into a `Func<Product, TPropertyType>`?

I specifically want to pass this into the <strike>`Where`</strike> or `OrderBy` linq methods used by entity framework.

I'm also open to other suggestions not using `Expressions`, but I highly doubt it's possible.

**Edit 1**: Removed the `where` use case as `Where` and `OrderBy` will have different implementations Removed in an attempt to narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: `Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, TPropertyType>>(...)` ?

Comment: I cannot pass The generic `TPropertyType` because I don't know what it is at compile time.

Comment: This is tricky because you have to specify what the body of the lambda will be. For instance, `Where` requires a lambda with a conditional check returning a boolean value. On the other hand, `OrderBy` requires a lambda with no conditionaly check but rather a property selector. You need completely different Expressions for each type. Is the intent that you'll conditionally build out different Expressions based on the LINQ method you hit, or are you trying to build a one-size-fits-all Expression?

Comment: To be a bit more clear, `Where` would be given an Expression that was created using `Expression.GreaterThan` (or something similar that produces a conditional statement) which is then passed into `Expression.Lambda` and given to `Where`. Whereas `OrderBy` would be given an Expression that was created using `Expression.Property` and passed to `Expression.Lambda`. So you can see how the Expression has to be constructed differently based on which LINQ method you use.

Comment: You also mentioned that you don't know what `TPropertyType` is at compile time. Entity Frameworks `Where`/`OrderBy` requires you to specify the Type at compile time, so if you don't know what it is at compile time then you'll never be able to pass into LINQ unless you're doing some form of dynamic invocation at runtime. You _must_ know what the `TPropertyType` is at compile-time in order to send any Expression into LINQ.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Thanks, I will edit the question an narrow it down to the `OrderBy` Method so that it's easier to answer. And I guess I could write some logic to create different `TPropertyType`s based on the `propertyType` value. If you post an answer with the `TPropertyType` as a string, I'll accept it as you explained the rest of the constraints.

Comment: You will still need `TPropertyType` to be known at compile time because C# is a strongly typed language. You can build the Expression in a generic fashion with strings and stuff, but when you pass it to LINQ you will have to cast it to a strongly typed object with the types all known. Does that still make this viable?

Comment: Yes this will still work. `if (propertyType == typeof(string)) { return new Expression.Lambda(Func<Product, string>(...)); }` obviously I could abstract this to some factory or something similar. I'm still not sure how to implement the expression though.

Comment: He said the property type isn’t known at compile time, so that won’t work. He can’t use `typeof(string)` because it’s not known.

Comment: Same person, I'm the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with generating expressions for `OrderBy` and `Where`. As  Johnathon Sullinger said in comments, you must know type of property you ordering by at compile time, because it is mentioned in signature of `OrderBY`. However you don't have to know it for `Where`:

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var products = new List<Product> {
        new Product { Name = "ZZZ"},
        new Product { Name = "AAA"}
    };

    var propertyName = "Name";

    var ordered = products.AsQueryable().OrderBy(GetOrderExpression<string>(propertyName));
    Console.WriteLine(ordered.ElementAt(0).Name);
    Console.WriteLine(ordered.ElementAt(1).Name);

    var filtered = products.AsQueryable().Where(GetWhereExpression(propertyName, "AAA"));
    Console.WriteLine(filtered.Count());
    Console.WriteLine(filtered.ElementAt(0).Name);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static Expression<Func<Product, TKey>> GetOrderExpression<TKey>(string propertyName)
{
    var prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
    var prop = Expression.Property(prm, typeof(Product), propertyName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, TKey>>(prop, "p", new[] { prm });

    return lambda;
}

static Expression<Func<Product, bool>> GetWhereExpression(string propertyName, object value)
{
    var prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
    var prop = Expression.Property(prm, typeof(Product), propertyName);
    var equal = Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(value));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(equal, "p", new[] { prm });

    return lambda;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, this worked! I suppose I could swap out the `Expression.Equal` for other types of comparisons, in the `GetWhereExpression`?

Comment: Happy to help. Yes, you can do it.